# Code Classic ASP in Linux

Tags: linux, asp-classic, editor

What should i use to code Classic ASP under Linux. I have really tried to use Emacs and Vim but I don't have the time to learn them.

What i'm looking for is:

- Syntax highlighting
- Code Browser (Ctags)
- Preferably som sort of code insight

Something like Ultra Edit or E-texteditor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking here, but if you are simply looking for a text-editor, my recommendations would be:

Console-based:

- jed (simple, with a DOS Edit-like menubar, supports syntax-highlighing)
- nano / pico (even simpler)

X-based:

- Kate (KDE, syntax-highlighing)
- Mousepad (like notepad)
- SciTE (syntax-highlighing)

There are of course likely to be a gazillion other text-editors better than the ones listed above, but these are the ones I tend to use.

Answer (score 1):

I played with BlueFish for a while when I was contemplating switching over completely and I liked it better than Kate. But, you will have to add the code to enable ASP highlighting. Its floating around numerous places - I found it in short order with a quick trip to the trusty ole Google. ;)

But that is just my personal preference. Your mileage may vary.